# Use of the ship tag

Tags: discussion, tags

While answering this recent question:

[Finding details about an immigration from England to New Zealand / Australia](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18931/1006)

I recommended using the tag [ship](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ship) to look for questions about researching a ship that a passenger sailed on, but it occurs to me that might not be useful.

Should we have a means of distinguishing research about ships (the vessels themselves vs. *an individual's transit on a particular voyage* of a ship)? If so, how should we go about it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the voyages of a ship are part of the ship history that it might be desirable to research.

For those, I think the tag for [ship](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ship) will suffice.  I think the crew should be considered part of the [ship](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ship) for tagging.

However, when looking at an individual’s journey on a ship a tag of [passenger-list](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passenger-list) may be more appropriate.